# adding Tags to a view when items are selected in a Spinner

Tags: android

I have this layout,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.asamater.constructionprojects.ChooseCatActivity"
android:background="@color/backgroundColor">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</LinearLayout>

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText7"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When the user clicks an item in the spinner. I want a tag(like the ones on stackoverflow) to populate the empty layout above the spinner. I am thinking of just creating a TextView in the onItemSelected method.
Is this the best way or is there existing classes that I can use to do this so I can avoid handling the activitylifecycle issues????

Comment: didn't get what actually you are trying to do ! can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: you know how on stackoverflow there are tags. Imagin there is a spinner with a list of items. every time a user selects an item. a tag(a TextView maybe) would show up in the empty layout above the spinner.

Comment: Simply place a TextView above the spinner, and populate it whenever an item is selected from the spinner. You can design the TextView to look like a Tag. You can listen for Spinner selection by using the OnItemSelectedListener().

Comment: Ok I did that, I was hoping that there is better way that would handle all the life cycle issues. Also the problem I'm having with my approach is that the LinaerLayout gets full after adding a few Tags. How can I make it so the tags are added to the next line or row in the LinaerLayout ?